# Where can I put Powershell modules that will be accessed by multiple users?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I used the variable $Env:PSModulePath , It provided two paths.

```
> C:\Users\My User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

Seems like My User will be accessible only for me. But my module will be used by multiple person and also when uninstalling my application [I am installing my module via msi], even if some other user uninstalls it should be removed.

Can I use "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\" for my application related module? Or is there any other better place ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can i use "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\" for my
>   application related module?

No. That place is not for you as noted in the section *"Rules for Installing Modules"* of the [module installation guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can decide yourself where you want to put the modules that are shared for multiple users.

Some options include:

- Create new folder in `Program Files`, and add that path to `PSModulePath`.
- Use a network share (though this means you need to change your execution policy to allow this), as [@Rubanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816760/1630171) said.
- Use the `All Users` folder for example.

Comment: Are you sure the Execution policy needs to be changed for importing modules? We have `RemoteSigned` and we are able to import modules (that are not signed) from a share without problems.

Comment: I think I'd prefer the third option. Microsoft should probably add a default location for admin-installed shared modules there.

Comment: @Rubanov: I cant answer this question for sure, because this is seems to be shady area.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/37024f85-bece-4646-8c3e-376dc2b32e9b/powershell-scripts-wont-run-from-a-network-drive?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your psm1 files on a shared drive. Then import the module with

```
Import-Module -Name "\\SERVERNAME\Use-MyModule.psm1"
```

You can find more info about adding a path to `PSModulePath` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326(v=vs.85).aspx).